# Allowed Footwear in prayer

Tags: tefilla, clothing

Is there a problem with wearing sandals or Crocs during Davening instead of regular footwear?  What is the source for this issue and what is the reason for this issue?

Comment: Aren't Crocs a staple on Yom Kippur and other such holidays?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The halachic gauge for how to dress for Hashem is how people dress in front of "great people" and every place is different ([Shulchan Aruch O.C. 91:5 MB 12-13](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49623&st=&pgnum=244)).  I assume that Israel has a more laid back standard than, say, the U.S.  In Israel, people might visit the Head of State in sandalim.

This opens a big can of worms.  Can a person wear jeans and a polo shirt?  Unpressed slacks?  No tie? Scuffed shoes?

Comment: flip flops in America: http://www.usatoday.com/news/nation/2005-07-19-flip-flops_x.htm

Comment: The fact that it was controversial strengthens the question.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on the location. [R Shlomo Aviner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shlomo_Aviner) writes in his book On the air (full book available [here](https://www.ateret.org.il/uploads/files/radio%20-%20ch%201-277.pdf)), p. 40, that it is acceptable in locations where wearing sandals (he speaks without socks) is respectable.

> One is required to daven dressed in a way in which he would stand
>   before a king. How one stands before a king is dependent on the place
>   and time in which one lives. The Beit Yosef says that one is obligated
>   to daven barefoot (Orach Chaim 91:5). Not only is it permissible but
>   one is obligated to daven barefoot. Obviously, today if someone
>   shows up barefoot to daven, he would be thrown out of the shul.
>
> Therefore, it is dependent on reality. **Wearing sandals nowadays is
>   respectable (this applies in Israel; other locations may differ).**
>   Wearing flip-flops, however, is not considered respectable since a
>   person wears them when getting out of the shower or at the pool or on
>   the beach.